# Android AsyncTask getting JSON but not returning/crashing only on actual device

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-asynctask, http-get

I have an `AsyncTask` that returns a `JSON Object` which contains a list of potential servers for a user to connect to. If I am using an emulated device, it returns no problem, however, now that I am testing it on a actual tablet, it is throwing errors. What is confusing is that there is a null pointer error thrown on what I believe to be my `url connection`; however, the AsyncTask is able to log the appropriate answer that should be returned at the end of the task. In addition to this, the error is only thrown on the tablet - It works fine on all of the emulated devices I have used.

AsyncTask (doInBackground): (the error says that there is a null pointer at the line containing `new InputStreamReader(connectionrates.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));`

```
private class UpdateUtilities extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.d("agasg", "asgadsgdsb");
        try {
            byte[] userpass = "something".getBytes(); // can avoid if allow rest call to be done outside of logging in
            URL urlrates = new URL("something");
            String basicAuthrates = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass, Base64.DEFAULT);
            HttpURLConnection connectionrates = (HttpURLConnection) urlrates.openConnection();
            connectionrates.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connectionrates.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuthrates);
            BufferedReader inrates = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connectionrates.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer responseutils = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = inrates.readLine()) != null) {
                responseutils.append(inputLine);
            }

            inrates.close();
            Log.d("hi",responseutils.toString());
            return responseutils.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "error failed - UtilitiesUpdateDialog";
    }
```

StackTrace:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/agasg: asgadsgdsb
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: (This is just Trace Log)java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SBServiceAPI.getService(SBServiceAPI.java:641)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.<init>(HttpEngine.java:211)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:342)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:203)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
I/System.out:     at com.example.schadtj.portalapp.Dialogs.UpdateUtilitiesDialogFragment$UpdateUtilities.doInBackground(UpdateUtilitiesDialogFragment.java:119)
I/System.out:     at com.example.schadtj.portalapp.Dialogs.UpdateUtilitiesDialogFragment$UpdateUtilities.doInBackground(UpdateUtilitiesDialogFragment.java:105)
I/System.out:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
I/System.out:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
I/System.out:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
I/System.out:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
I/System.out:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
I/System.out:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-1399-644722104: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
**Log is returned here - didn't include result**
```

Comment: Check the line which throws NPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not yet opened connection before using. Try this and let me know.

connectionrates.connect();
before doing
connectionrates.getInputStream()

This will surely resolve this issue.